# Ifelse in a for loop not yielding desired output

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataset with 2 columns namely, "time(Ti)" and "counter(Co)". Whenever the counter is 1 , I am supposed to calculate time difference between that "row time" and previous "row time" .

To achieve the above requirement, I am using the below logic

```
for (i in 1:length(file1$counter))
{  
  n1 <-  ifelse(file1$counter==1,(file1$TIME[(i)] - file1$TIME[(i-1)]),0)
}
```

But I am getting a standard output as `0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0` instead of `0 0 2 1 4 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0`
Also the n1 is by default shown as Time Series with Start = 1, End = 20 and
Frequency = 1.

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized, so you shouldn't need the outer explicit for loop or you would need to use `if(..) ... else ...`

Answer (score 2):

As docendo discimus noted, `ifelse` is a vectorized operation in R. You can omit the `for` loop in order to get the desired result. Here's an example:

```
filename   = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
counter    = c(1, 2, 3) 
df = data.frame(filename, counter) 
df$n1 <- ifelse(df$counter == 1, "one", "other")
```

Which gives us an updated `df` of:

```
  filename counter    n1
1       aa       1   one
2       bb       2 other
3       cc       3 other
```

Comment: Thanks Matt & docendo. As suggested , only the ifelse condition is used .Still I am getting the old result. The problem has been posted in detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29669891/how-to-find-the-difference-in-tme-series-data . Please throw some more light on how can it be dealt with.