# How to find the difference in Tme Series data?

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 2 columns TIME and COUNTER. Whenever the counter is 1, I'm trying to calculate time difference between that row's TIME value and previous row's TIME.

My data

```
TIME COUNTER 
24   0        
28   0       
30   1       
31   1      
35   1      
36   1       
40   1       
42   0       
44   0       
46   0      
48   0       
50   0       
52   0       
54   1       
56   1       
58   1       
60   1       
62   1       
64   0       
66   0
```

The code I was trying was:

```
for (i in 1:length(file1$COUNTER))
{  
  n1 <-  ifelse(file1$COUNTER==1,(file1$TIME[(i)] - file1$TIME[(i-1)]),0)
}
```

The actual output is:

```
 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0
```

But my desired output is:

```
0 0 2 1 4 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0
```

Where am I going wrong??

And also the n1 is by default shown as below. What does exactly mean??

```
> n1

Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 20 
Frequency = 1
```

Comment: working on the same assignment?

Comment: Also your series seems to be a `ts` so you can use `diff.ts`: `ifelse(file1$COUNTER==1,c(NA,diff(file1$TIME)),0)`

Comment: Please provide the output of `dput(file1)` so we unambiguously know what you have.  If `file1` is a two column `"ts"` class object then try: `diff(file1[,1]) * file1[,2]` .  (If its something else then this expression would need to be modified appropriately.)

Comment: @GGrothendieck: dput(file1) is:  structure(list(TIME = c(24L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 35L, 36L, 40L, 42L, 
44L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 64L, 66L), 
    COUNTER = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("TIME", "COUNTER"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

Answer (score 1):

```
file1 <- structure(list(TIME = c(24L, 28L, 30L, 31L, 35L, 36L, 40L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 54L, 56L, 58L, 60L, 62L, 64L, 66L), COUNTER = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("TIME", "COUNTER" ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L)) 
ifelse(file1$COUNTER, c(NA, diff( file1$TIME)), 0) 
[1] 0 0 2 1 4 1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 2 0 0
```